# How to create DB edges from the model

Tags: c#, orientdb

I started to use OrientDB-NET.binary. I have created 2 Classes: BusinessService and BusinessServiceGroup based on Basic Node.

The relations are:

- BusinessService->BusinessServiceGroup
- BusinessService->BusinessService
- BusinessServiceGroup->BusinessServiceGroup

Also I've created 2 Intermediate classes:

- DependsOnBusinessService
- InvolvesIntoBusinessServiceGroup
- DependsOnBusinessServiceGroup

Code

```
public class BasicNode
{
    public ORID ORID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class BusinessService : BasicNode
{
    public List<ORID> in_DependsOnBusinessService { get; set; }
    public List<ORID> out_DependsOnBusinessService { get; set; }
    public List<ORID> out_InvolvesInBusinessServiceGroup { get; set; }
}

public class BusinessServiceGroup : BasicNode
{
    public List<ORID> in_DependsOnBusinessServiceGroup { get; set; }
    public List<ORID> out_DependsOnBusinessServiceGroup { get; set; }
    public List<ORID> in_InvolvesIntoBusinessServiceGroup { get; set; }
}
```

Edges:

```
public class DependsOnBusinessService
{
    [OProperty(Alias = "in", Serializable = false)]
    public ORID In { get; set; }
    [OProperty(Alias = "out", Serializable = false)]
    public ORID Out { get; set; }
}

public class DependsOnBusinessServiceGroup
{
    [OProperty(Alias = "in", Serializable = false)]
    public ORID In { get; set; }
    [OProperty(Alias = "out", Serializable = false)]
    public ORID Out { get; set; }
}

public class InvolvesIntoBusinessServiceGroup
{
    [OProperty(Alias = "in", Serializable = false)]
    public ORID In { get; set; }
    [OProperty(Alias = "out", Serializable = false)]
    public ORID Out { get; set; }
}
```

Then I create the "Migration":

```
    [HttpGet("v1")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
        log.AppendLine("Migrating to version 1.");
        using (ODatabase database = new ODatabase(_connection.GlobalDatabaseAlias))
        {
            if (!database.Schema.IsClassExist<BusinessService>())
            {
                database
                    .Create.Class<BusinessService>()
                    .Extends<OVertex>()
                    .CreateProperties()
                    .Run();
                log.AppendLine("BusinessService vertex class has been created.");
            }

            if (!database.Schema.IsClassExist<BusinessServiceGroup>())
            {
                database
                    .Create.Class<BusinessServiceGroup>()
                    .Extends<OVertex>()
                    .CreateProperties()
                    .Run();

                log.AppendLine("BusinessServiceGroup vertex class has been created.");
            }

            if (!database.Schema.IsClassExist<InvolvesIntoBusinessServiceGroup>())
            {
                database
                    .Create.Class<InvolvesIntoBusinessServiceGroup>()
                    .Extends<OEdge>()
                    .CreateProperties()
                    .Run();

                log.AppendLine("InvolvesIntoBusinessServiceGroup edge class has been created.");
            }

            if (!database.Schema.IsClassExist<DependsOnBusinessService>())
            {
                database
                    .Create.Class<DependsOnBusinessService>()
                    .Extends<OEdge>()
                    .CreateProperties()
                    .Run();

                log.AppendLine("DependsOnBusinessService edge class has been created.");
            }

            if (!database.Schema.IsClassExist<DependsOnBusinessServiceGroup>())
            {
                database
                    .Create.Class<DependsOnBusinessServiceGroup>()
                    .Extends<OEdge>()
                    .CreateProperties()
                    .Run();

                log.AppendLine("DependsOnBusinessServiceGroup edge class has been created.");
            }
        }

        log.AppendLine("Migrating to version 1 has succeeded");

        return Ok(log.ToString());
    }
```

The migration is done successfully but when I open the OrientDBStudio I see that Links are not Filled with ClassName.

[image: EmptyLinks]

So what I'm doing wrong? Or this behavior is normal and I must set Classlinks with SQL.